# Redirect or not? when updating permalink?

Tags: url-rewriting

Heres an example of a SO link. I was wondering, if the user has updated the subject of the link should i do a redirect or a plain 200? A redirect will allow the user to have the most current title in their address bar (where i usually copy/paste from) but then again the title part doesnt really matter.

If i do something other then a 200 what should i do? and should i do something other then a 200?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170934/call-reset-but-outside-of-a-form/4170968#4170968
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a redirect 301. Google seems to take care of 301 redirect ;)

> If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results, we recommended that you use a server-side 301 redirect. This is the best way to ensure that users and search engines are directed to the correct page. The 301 status code means that a page has permanently moved to a new location.

That comes directly from :
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633

It could be really good for pages/topics with a lot of external links and history, but for small new pages/topic/articles, i'm not sure it worth the time working on it !

Comment: I already need to do the url query. Putting one if and a simple redirect line is as much trouble as this reply. none at all ;) and thanks, i was thinking of NOT using permanent redirect for some odd reason